# Fire Google Tag Manager GTM Tags on Angular Clicks

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

My development team has created a single page website with many links like this:

```
<a href="javascript:" ng-click="setTab('geography');">Geography</a>
```

and

```
<a href="javascript:" ng-click="setTab('demography');">Demographics</a>
```

How can I create Google Tag Manager tags which can differentiate these as separate events since they have the same href as "javascript:"? Is there a way to make the event name based off of the anchor text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GTM, you can try to utilise the {{Click Text}} variable which, according to [GA documentation](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106961?hl=en), is

> Click Text: The visible text inside the clicked element.

You would just need to make sure that the anchor element is your clicked element, and the text would follow from that.